# Активация учётной записи за/против, варианты

Tags: защита, авторизация, активация

Недавно задался вопросом по поводу авторизации.
При регистрации на сайте автоматически генерируется пароль и отправляется на почтовый ящик.
Интересны за и против этого способа и другие варианты на подобие активации через уникальный код.

Comment: С активацией понятно, ещё хотелось бы узнать какие ещё экзотические способы бывают так сказать для расширения кругозора.

Comment: Бывают активация через мобильный телефон: высылается код по смс.
Можно привязать например к ICQ|Jabber и послать еще туда код активации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Активация учетной записи через письмо заставляет пользователя делать массу вещей, прежде чем он увидит Ваш драгоценный сайт. Как правило страдает первое впечатление от сайта..

Мое мнение:

1. Никогда не генерируйте пароль автоматически и не посылайте его на почту. Дайте пользователю свободу выбора, и избавьте его от необходимости менять этот пароль сразу после регистрации.
2. Отправьте пользователю на почту ссылку для активации, **но** предоставьте ему **сразу** доступ к сайту. + показывайте где-нибудь на видном месте, что аккаунт нужно активировать. Почистить раз в неделю/месяц неактивные и неактивированые аккаунты не так сложно
3. Сделайте возможность входа посредством OpenID или при помощи популярных соц. сетей. Не каждый пользователь захочет регистрироваться, а вот сразу получить доступ - уже другое дело

Answer (score 5):

Отправкой на телефон кода активации.. Но тут думаю люди испугаются за средства на счету)

Answer (score 4):

Терпеть не могу активацию учетки через письмо на мыло!!!

Бывает что сижу на работе и регистрируюсь на каком-нибудь ресурсе на свое мыло, а открыто в это время рабочее, и приходится перелогиниваться, подтверждать то что я не бот, и опять перелогиниваться, да я к тому времени рискую забыть на кой черт мне этот сайт нужен был...

P.S. все изложенное IMHO

**UPD.**

Об усиленной защите.

Регистрировался на стэке, не используя левые акки.

1.Ввел мало символов в пароле - назад.

2.Ввел не ту капчу (жесткая видать попалась) - назад.

3.Ввел ту капчу, ту длину пароля, но в пароле нужны разные символы/регистры - назад...

Мне показалось это все немного лишним.

Comment: В большинстве современных браузеров присуствтует режим инкогнито (хром), в фаерфоксе - приватный просмотр. Он решит ваши проблемы :)

Comment: Навязанные **кем-то** проблемы!

Answer (score 3):

Я за активацию учетной записи только на тех сайтах, где это действительно нужно. Т.е., на e-mail будут постоянно приходить какие-то важные уведомления.

Answer (score 2):

Активация аккаунта с помощью почтового ящика создана не для того, что бы раздражать пользователей. Первоначальное и самое главное ее предназначение - обеспечение правильности и корректности введенных регистрационных данных пользователя.
Если пользователь ввел неверный адрес почтового ящика, то сразу же исчезают функции:
► Восстановления утерянного пароля при помощи почты.
► Рассылка новостей или информационных писем, в том числе диалоги с администрацией портала.
► Смена почтового ящика(как подтвердить смену?).
► Возможность просмотра профильной информации в регистрационном письме пользователем. 
Следовательно он не сможет вспомнить свой логин или даже адрес сайта в случае его потери.
► Защита от ботов.
и многие другие...
Рекомендую, для сохранения анонимности данных пользователя, на почту не высылать пароль, вдруг адресат будет неправильным.

Comment: ИМХО - пусть юзер сам бы решал, надо ему на почту слать его или нет, так честнее будет, ато без меня меня женили. Защита от ботов? Да ладно, можно написать супер пупер каптчу, и никто не пройдет, можно эту каптчу через пол года сменить, для верности, и ботов не будет. ИМХО =)

Comment: Согласен, вариант "пусть юзер сам решает" является серебренной пулей.

Comment: Смена почтового ящика(как подтвердить смену?). - почтовый ящик чтобы подтвердить смену почтового ящика это пять

Comment: Да, иногда оказываешься в неприятной ситуации: сменить почтовый ящик невозможно ибо старый недоступен, а подтвердить это действие нужно именно с его помощью. Но зато мы получаем дополнительную защиту данных, если кто-то захочет полностью "захапать" себе акк(а следовательно и сменить адрес почты на свой), то ему придется еще и получить доступ к email аккаунта. 
Можно много обсуждать эту тему(как лучше, а как хуже), но каждый веб-разрабочик, руководствуясь особенностями своего проекта и личными принципами, сам выбирает средства подтверждения редактирования профиля.

Answer (score 1):

Зло. Вот Вам не пофиг, реальный у меня email или нет? С точки зрения рассылки спама - вариант самое оно, а как для людей - ну его..